# The use of "hey" in North America

Tags: differences, slang, greetings, canadian-english, north-american-english

Having had my formative years in New Zealand, I was born in South Africa.  I vaguely recall when I was VERY young having someone tell me when I said "hey" that "hay is what horses eat".

I got that then it was more when people would yell "hey" across a room to attract attention, and that was considered a bit rude for that purpose.

However in my adult years in NZ and the UK, a casual nod and a "hey", or "hey, what's up?" was a perfectly acceptable greeting.

Having recently moved to Canada, I greeted someone casually with that yesterday to be told again "that's what horses eat".  I felt a bit rebuffed, but decided to ignore it until I could research it - ie, ask on here!.

Is this just a North American thing? Or just possibly this individual's view? Same age and gender as me.

Comment: I'm Canadian and I say 'hey' all the time. It's a more casual, familiar form of 'hi.' I've heard "hay is for horses" but have never had anyone apply it to me when greeting them informally!

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yuFI5KSPAt4

Comment: 'Hey, is for horses' is a complete non-sequitur.  It can be used as either a pithy bon mot to jostle a friend, or a snide comment  to completely distract and put off a mere acquaintance.  Any reasonable person who is non-confrontational and relatively interested in the conversation will more than likely never say it unless you know them well.

Comment: The person that said that back to you was either 1. being facetious, or 2. has an irrationally stubborn refusal to accept "hey" as a standard part of modern English. Either 1. laugh with them at their "cute" jest or 2. ignore them.

Comment: @Michael Edenfield: I think back in 1738 when Jonathon Swift wrote the first recorded instance *as a riposte*, it would be in response to *"Hey"* used as a casual/vulgar/insulting way of grabbing someone's attention. Akin to *Oi, you!* in modern BrE, but I don't think there even *is* a modern American equivalent. But I doubt many/any Americans (or Canadians) really object to *"Hey"* instead of *"Hello"* - so effectively for them it's a "cute" joke that falls flat if you look at it too closely (it still works for us aitch-dropping Cockneys, though! :)

Comment: I can't help but be a little impressed at how the asker here managed to spend his formative years before even being born. Such efficiency of life!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Gives you more time for a fruitful adulthood, I'd imagine.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ah the wording, perhaps, generally in my circles 'formative years' is your teenage / uni years.

Comment: @MarkMayo Exactly—hence my impression! (Only a good-humoured joke, mind, at the somewhat dangling participle. It’s not like the sentence wasn’t fully understandable anyway.)

Comment: Ah now I see what you meant, yeah, that does read odd now :)

Answer (score 18):

Pretty much the only time I remember hearing *"Hay is for horses"* intended as an actual admonition, as opposed to a lighthearted and humorous response, was in elementary school. I think our teachers used the phrase to remind us that "Hey, Mrs. Johnson" was an inapproriately informal way to get a teacher's attention – that we should try something like, "Excuse me, Mrs. Johnson" instead.

So many people heard that refrain growing up, though, that I've heard it get tossed out reflexively every now and then.

As for what message the person you greeted was trying to send, it's hard to say for certain.  I think some people respond to "Hey" that way in an attempt to sound witty, while others may have misinterpreted our lesson from childhood to mean: *using "hey" when addressing someone is always rude*.  In the former case, I don't think anything so trite ever comes off as very humorous; in the latter, it's professing ignorance for language, since the word *isn't* inherently rude, and isn't even spelled the same as its cow-feed homophone.

For the record, NOAD even lists "hello" among the word's definitions:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You're mixing up two different "Heys" (or the Canadian you greeted is).

The reprimand *"'ay is for 'orses"* is/was supposed to teach you to say *"Pardon?"* instead of *"Eh?"* if you hadn't heard something, and wanted it to be repeated.

The modern American "greeting" *"Hey"* is really just a variant of *"Hi"*, *"Hello"*, etc. Which is only vaguely related to the long-standing *"Hey!"* variant of *"Hoi!"*, *"Ho there!"*, etc., used as an interjection, or a means of attracting attention.

Comment: Ah yes.  However, He certainly seemed to think it was that "for horses one".

Comment: I'm Canadian, and I've never heard of "for horses" being used in the context of "eh?".  I have, however, been subjected to many a "for horses" whenever I would "Hey" someone.  You're clearly mistaken in stating that the "for horses" is supposed to reprimand you for saying "Eh?" _alone_.

Comment: @Geoist No.  It was originally used in England to teach Cockney kids to say "pardon" or something similarly polite, rather than "eh".

Comment: @Geoist: [Partridge acknowledges](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=tvRp1whVFUsC&pg=PA539&dq=%22An+inferior+cigar+low%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=G0UJUPylBJDssgbRkYiGCQ&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22An%20inferior%20cigar%20low%22&f=false) that the first recorded use (Jonathon Swift, 1738) was a counter to "Hey!" in a "beckoning" context. But [my definition](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22horses+used+as+a+disdainful+rejoinder%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) comes first in his later editions.

Comment: Here in N America, since we never drop initial H's, it's less likely that "Eh" and "Hey" are confused. Probably the *saying* 'hay is for horses' came over the pond intact, but here it's used as a response to "Hey". I can attest to its use as an admonishment in the late '60s/early '70s USA.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have no objection to the historical context, clearly you've mastered that subject.  Your accusation, however, that "'ay is for 'orses" **is supposed to** teach you to say 'Pardon?' instead of 'Eh?'" is inaccurate.

Comment: @Geoist: I can only repeat that the "Don't say 'Eh?', say 'Pardon?'" sense is given *first* in the later editions of Partridge. I'll also note that "Hey" is *never* used instead of "Pardon?" in my experience, so possibly the jokey allusion to *'ay for 'orses* is more established in British (Cockney) usage, where aitches are commonly dropped by people whose "common" speech is more likely to be thus corrected. I'll also note that "Hey" for "Hi" is very much an Americanism (but it is spreading to Britain recently).

Comment: Maybe in Canada, eh is for orses?

Answer (score 10):

From an AmE speaker, 'hey' is perfectly fine in the US, people use it all the time.

I remember hearing that more than once as a child, "Hay is for horses." in response to 'hey'. It sounds like it was supposed to stop you from using 'hey' but it never did. It comes across more as a (not particularly successful) attempt at a clever saying.

It's not formal at all, but also not at all vulgar. Just plain informal.

Comment: It's only "not particularly successful" for Americans/Canadians, who don't habitually drop their aitches, and who also don't tend to say *"Eh?"* instead of *"Pardon? I didn't hear that."*

Comment: In AmE, 'pardon' sounds (to my native speaker's ears) not as common as 'excuse me? ...' or 'I'm sorry, ...'. Actually 'What?' though a bit blunt and nominally rude, just might be more common anyway.

Comment: I wasn't intending to get sidetracked into what alternatives people actually say in that context - "pardon" was shorter than "excuse me", and I figured most people would at least understand what context I meant. Which I thought might *not* be the case if I'd used that other common BrE alternative - *"What?"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Sidetracked? Isn't that what comments are for? Or rather what answers are not. Anyway, comments are fair game. Where were we?

Comment: I *think* we've just established that Americans are just as likely as Brits to say *"What?"* here. Which doesn't derail my position as set out above. But I *have* set some store by the idea that Americans don't say *"Eh?"* very often, so I'll have to squirm a bit if you tell me they commonly say that too!

Comment: Let your squirming fears be assuaged. I don't think many Americans say '..., eh?' except in ironic imitation of Canadians. But now that I think of it, 'uptalk' probably is the phenomenon with pretty much the same semantic purpose as 'eh'. Except I've heard uptalk in all sorts of accents, GenAmE, IndE, older people,.. uh.. well at least the IndE surprised me.

Answer (score 8):

I believe the negative response, "Hey(Hay) is for horses" is used to be a political ploy.  I've seen it used to put down someone as if they were implying that its use is vulgar. A secondary put down might be "Hay?  Are you calling me a horse, punk?"

Its used as a way of confusing the person offering the greeting and making them pause awkwardly and question their cultural up-bringing/identity.   A good response back might be, "You're not from around here, are you  buddy?"

Comment: Both those quotes sound like something that Clint Eastwood would say. :)

Comment: I have spent a lot of time watching Clint Eastwood.

Answer (score 2):

There are several rhymes/sayings that start with "Hay is for horses", which have differing tones:

> Hay is for horses, but cows eat it too. If you don't be quiet, I'll
>   feed some to you.
>
> Hay is for horses, straw is cheaper, grass is free, Hippies smoke it... why don't we!
>
> Hay is for horses, grass is cheaper, straw is free, buy a farm and you
>   get all three.

The first rhyme has more of a cautionary tone, but the second and third are more in jest/humor than anything else.  The word "Hey" was used as an opportunity to use this rhyme in conversation.

I'm having trouble coming up with sources for the variants of the saying, so take this with a grain of salt.

Answer (score -1):

I feel that it's O.K. to use "hey" as a greeting to someone you know well, but otherwise, not.  And I really find it rude to use "Hey!" to get someone's attention in order to correct or to reprimand them. I feel it is an insult to be yelled at in that manner.  Rather, I think, in order to call someone's attention to a perceived fault, one should call them by name or say, "Excuse me," in a polite voice, then proceed with whatever complaint necessary.

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE]. In online communications, using CAPITALS is usually considered as shouting. Click the edit link below you post, then the little ? in a circle to see editing help. You can use *italics* for emphasis, or **bold**.